# No module named 'dlib'

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, msbuild, python-3.7, dlib

I am using windows 10 
python 3.7.4

I have  a code where it imports dlib

```
import dlib
```

But when I try to install it using  pip install dlib it throws an error

```
ERROR : Command errored out with exit status 1 : 
......
```

I even tired installing cmake 
and [This dlib file](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/92/05c3b98636661cb80d190a5a777dd94effcc14c0f6893222e5ca81e74fbc/dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz) and tried to copy paste them into site-packages and tried

```
python setup.py install
```

It throws an error saying

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
      Failed to run MSBuild command:
```

What should be done to resolve this ??

Thanks to anyone who took time to read to this query and tired to solve this . Best of luck for your work :) ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found it ..
We need to install visual studio build tools for C++ which will be around 4.53 GB .
Then by using

```
pip install dlib
```

It was installed easily.

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 6):

If you get a fail error when trying to install, try the following:

Install CMAKE

```
pip install cmake
```

Then Install dlib

```
pip install dlib
```